# How to give android MediaPlayer a String Path?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, media

I wrote a Media Player in my app and wrote this code below:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file);
```

I want to give my mediaplayer this String path instead of a uri:

```
String path = "http://example.org/file.mp3";
```

How can I do that?
Guys Please answer my question with some code!!!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://example.org/file.mp3");
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(context, uri);
        player.start();
```

Comment: what should I put inside the "context" ?